# Compare one salary with another and add comments column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare one salary with another and add comments column to display whose salary is higher than who.

I used self join to compare but I do not know how to include a comment column to explain whose is higher than who.

Expect something like shown below:

```
empid   name     salary comments
1       raj      30000  "raj sal less then dev and sunil but greater then prashant,dilip,anil"
2       prashant 24935  "prashant sal less then raj,dev,anil,sunil but greather then dilip"
3       dev      38572  
4       anil     29845  
5       sunil    48201  
6       dilip    12093
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?  and it will be easier with two columns - one for those who get less and one for those who get more.

Comment: i tried but unable to write the query to get the comments column add with comments on salary comparison for each employee..

Comment: @sagi It can be done in a single column, i agree though over two columns would be more useful, especially when it comes to actually _doing_ something with the data.

Comment: Didn't say its impossible,just more efficient and easier. This structure is not good either way anyways.

Comment: @sagi i agree with you there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `STUFF` function within a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT t1.empid, t1.name, t1.salary,
CASE WHEN t1.salary = (SELECT MIN(t3.salary) FROM yourtable t3) 
     THEN t1.name + ' has the lowest salary.'
     WHEN t1.salary = (SELECT MAX(t3.salary) FROM yourtable t3)
     THEN t1.name + ' has the highest salary.'
     ELSE t1.name +'''s salary is less than ' + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(T2.name AS VARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM yourtable T2 WHERE  T1.salary < T2.salary
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ' but greater than ' + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(T2.name AS VARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM yourtable T2 WHERE  T1.salary > T2.salary
     FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  + '.' 
END AS Comments 
FROM yourtable t1
GROUP BY t1.empid, t1.name, t1.salary
```

OUTPUT

```
empid  name     salary  Comments
1      raj      30000   raj's salary is less than dev, sunil but greater than prashant, anil, dilip.
2      prashant 24935   prashant's salary is less than raj, dev, anil, sunil but greater than dilip.
3      dev      38572   dev's salary is less than sunil but greater than raj, prashant, anil, dilip.
4      anil     29845   anil's salary is less than raj, dev, sunil but greater than prashant, dilip.
5      sunil    48201   sunil has the highest salary.
6      dilip    12093   dilip has the lowest salary.
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ebca/63/0